# Xcode Apple Clang enable avx512

Tags: xcode, clang, avx, avx2, avx512

In Xcode(Version 10.1 (10B61)), I used Macro as below to detect AVX512 support.

```
#ifdef __SSE4_1__
#error "sse4_1"
#endif

#ifdef __AVX__
#error "avx"
#endif

#ifdef __AVX2__
#error "avx2"
#endif

#ifdef __AVX512__
#error "avx512"
#endif
```

In default Build Settings, **SSE4_1** is active, but avx, avx2 and is not. When I add **-mavx** in Building Settings-->Apple Clang-Custom Compiler Flags-->Other C Flags, that enable **AVX**, further adding **-mavx2** to enable **AVX** and **AVX2**, but Unknow argument: '-mavx512'. 
How do you enable avx512 and detect it?
It seems like there are few Macro to detect avx512.

```
#define __AVX512BW__ 1  
#define __AVX512CD__ 1  
#define __AVX512DQ__ 1  
#define __AVX512F__ 1  
#define __AVX512VL__ 1
```

What's differences between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AVX512 isn't a single extension, and doesn't have a specific-enough meaning in this context to be useful.  Compilers only deal with *specific* CPU features, like AVX512F, AVX512DQ, AVX512CD, etc.

All CPUs that support any AVX512 extensions must support AVX512F, the "Foundation".  **AVX512F *is* the baseline AVX512 extension that other AVX512 extensions build on.**

In code that wants to use AVX512 intrinsics, you should look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512 and pick a set of extensions that are available together on one CPU you care about, e.g. F + CD and VL, DQ, BW on currently-available Skylake-X.

Then for example use `#if defined(__AVX512BW__) && defined(__AVX512VL__)` before code that uses `vpermt2w` on 256-bit vectors or something.  **`__AVX512(anything)__` implies `__AVX512F__`**; that's the one extension you don't have to check for separately.

But if you *only* used AVX512F instructions, they yeah just check for that macro.

---

**You should pretty much never use `-mavx512f` directly**: use `-march=skylake-avx512`, `-march=knl`, `-march=znver4`, **`-march=native`**, or whatever to enable other AVX512 extensions.

Or `-march=x86-64-v4` for a generic set of AVX-512 features supported by Skylake-AVX512 and others except Xeon Phi, without implying tuning for a specific ISA.  (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Microarchitecture_levels).  On macOS, you know you're only going to be dealing with Intel CPUs, so tune for them as well as enabling extensions with `-march=icelake-client` or similar.

- The compiler knows which CPUs support which sets of extensions (or with `native` can detect which extensions the machine you're compiling on supports).  There are a lot of them, and leaving out important ones like AVX512VL (support for AVX512 instructions on 128-bit and 256-bit vectors) or Xeon Phi's AVX512ER (fast `1/x` and `1/sqrt(x)` with twice the precision of the normal AVX512 14-bit versions) could hurt performance significantly.  Especially AVX512ER is very important if you do any division or log/exp on Xeon Phi, because full-precision division is very slow on KNL compared to Skylake.
- `-march=x` implies `-mtune=x`,  enabling *tuning* options relevant for the target as well.  KNL is basically Silvermont with AVX512 bolted on, and has significant differences from `-mtune=skylake-avx512`.

**These are the same reasons you should generally not use `-mfma -mavx2` directly**, except that there are currently no AMD CPUs with AVX512, so there are only 2 main tuning targets (Xeon Phi and mainstream Skylake/CannonLake/Icelake), and they also support different sets of AVX512 extensions.  There is unfortunately no `-mtune=generic-avx2` tuning setting, but Ryzen supports almost all extensions that Haswell does (and the ones it doesn't GCC / clang won't use automatically, like transactional memory), so `-march=haswell` might be reasonable to make code tuned for CPUs with FMA, AVX2, popcnt, etc, without suffering too much on Ryzen.

---

Also relevant (for GCC, maybe not clang currently.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html):

- `-mprefer-vector-width=256` auto-vectorize with 256-bit vectors by default, in case most of the time is spent in non-vectorized loops.  Using 512-bit vectors reduces the max turbo clock speed by a significant amount on Intel Xeon CPUs (maybe not as much on i9 desktop versions of Skylake-X), so it can be a net slowdown to use 512-bit vectors in small scattered bits of your program.  So 256 is the default for `tune=skylake-avx512` in GCC, but KNL uses 512.
- `-mprefer-avx-128` the old version of the `-mprefer-vector-width=` option, before AVX512 existed.

Using AVX512 mask registers, 32 vector registers, and/or its new instructions, can be a significant win even at the same vector width, so it makes sense to enable AVX512 even if you don't want to use 512-bit vector width.  (Although sometimes code using intrinsics or auto-vectorization will compile in a worse way, instead of better, if AVX512 compare-into-register versions of comparison are available at all.  But hopefully anti-optimization bugs like that will be sorted out as AVX512 becomes more widely used.)

Comment: @Zboson: Thanks, fixed.  I probably left out a word when my brain got too far ahead of my fingers.  I meant to say "net loss" or "slowdown".

Comment: I still use the feature e.g. `-mavx2 -mfma` instead of the architecture generally. I guess I should change my habit.

Comment: @Zboson: yes, you should.  Especially with gcc, `-mtune=generic` (which `-mfma` doesn't change) cares about Sandybridge with questionable tuning options like `-mavx256-split-unaligned-load` ([Why doesn't gcc resolve \_mm256\_loadu\_pd as single vmovupd?](//stackoverflow.com/q/52626726)) that loads with `vmovups xmm` / `vinsertf128` any time the compiler can't *prove* at compile time that loads are guaranteed aligned.  So it can hurt Haswell / Skylake significantly, especially if data actually is aligned at runtime but you didn't tell the compiler about it, or it's almost always aligned.

Comment: That's quite interesting. That could explain why GCC still manually aligns arrays and then uses aligned loads in auto-vectorization even with `-mavx`.

Comment: update: `-march=x86-64-v4` can be a good idea for a generic AVX-512 feature-set.  SO isn't letting me save an edit.